# Bootstrap 4: Toggle Popover After Third Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a button that toggles a popover every **3 clicks** and **dismisses after clicking once** with Bootstrap v4.3.1. Is this possible?

**Code:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
  })
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="You've clicked on this button three times">Click 3 times</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by increment `var`

**AFTER 3 CLICK + FIRST TIME ONLY**

```js
var clicked = 0;

$('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
    clicked++;

    if (clicked >= 2) {
        clicked = 0;
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="You've clicked on this button three times">Click 3 times</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**AFTER 3 CLICK + EVERY TIME**

> IF YOU DON'T WANT DISMISS CLICK COUNT CHANGE `CLICKED TO 1`

```
$(this).on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
     clicked = 0; // CHANGE 1 IF YOU DONT WANT DISMISS CLICK 
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('dispose');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked = 0;
    $('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
        clicked++;
        if (clicked === 2) {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        $(this).on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
            clicked = 0; // CHANGE 1 IF YOU DONT WANT DISMISS CLICK 
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('dispose');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="You've clicked on this button three times">Click 3 times</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do you make it toggle after every 3 clicks instead of just the first 3?

Comment: can you need it every 3 click ?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to store the value on the element itself, to make it reusable for other buttons also:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function (e) {

    var target = e.target;
    var clickCount = parseInt(target.getAttribute('data-clickCounter'));

    if (clickCount) {
        if (clickcount === 2) {
            target.setAttribute('data-clickCounter', clickCount + 1);
            // add code to show pop-up
        } else if (clickcount === 3) {
            target.setAttribute('data-clickCounter', 0);
            // add code to hide the pop-up
        } else {
            target.setAttribute('data-clickCounter', clickCount + 1);
        }
    } else {
        target.setAttribute('data-clickCounter', 1);
    }
});
```